# Set state on form submit in a functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms

In my react typescript app - I have a `login` component and a `handleLoginRequest` function which sets the `userMessage` value:

```
function Login() {
  let [userMessage, setUserMessage] = useState("");

  return (
    <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={(e) => {
      setUserMessage(handleLoginRequest(e))
    }} >
      <label className="mr-sm-2">Email address:</label>
      <input type="email" className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Enter email" id="email" />
      <label className="mr-sm-2">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Enter password" id="password" />
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
      {userMessage}
    </form>

  );
}
```

Update: `handleLoginRequest` is a API request

```
const handleLoginRequest = (event: any): any => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const data = {
    email: event.target.email.value,
    password: event.target.password.value
  };

  axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_HTTP_PROXY}/api/v1/login`, data)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
      return res.data;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return err.message;
    });
}
```

**Expected behavior:**

When the form is submitted, the function `setUserMessage(handleLoginRequest(e))` is called. I expect that it update the value of `userMessage` to **login request received**.

**Actual result:**

No change in the value of `userMessage`

What is the fix here?

Comment: Please check this article - https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usestate-callback

Comment: @user2063635 Thanks will definitely check and update if it answers my question!

Comment: I've just run your code and it does what you expect?

Comment: @ShaneCreedon Do you have some fiddle or something in which you can run this? I don't see it working though :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated answer per the question modification**

The issue is stemming from the fact you're trying to setState based on a axios post request. Axios requests are asynchronous, meaning they will happen out of order with the program control flow. Therefore, to solve this issue, it is important you only make a call to `setUserMessage` when the request is complete.

#### Example Code:

```js
axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_HTTP_PROXY}/api/v1/login`, data)
  .then(res => {
    setUserMessage(res.data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Do Something with error response
    setUserMessage("Error: Something with the request went wrong.");
  });
```

I will link a codesandbox to demonstrate:

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-leakey-0jer4

Comment: Woah!!!!! Let me check and thanks! Yeah, it's working man! Let me see what is the problem in my project! Will update after checking :)

Comment: Awesome, glad to help.

Comment: Update: `handleLoginRequest` is an API request

Comment: I've updated the code pen above, you weren't setting the state in the request's response or in the request catch statements. Test it locally with the real request URL and let me know if your issue is solved.

Comment: I wanted to keep the functions separate and [single responsibile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)! This is working but the functions are not independent now! I'm trying to use `setUserMessage` as a callback parameter, hope that solves the problem!

Comment: I normally keep all the functions tied to a component inside the component itself, I don't see any reason to do it otherwise unless you're creating utility functions for all components in your component tree to use. But yes, you should be able to pass it as a callback parameter, good idea.